# Material Design Lite drawer breaks website on nav link click

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, material-design

I have encountered a weird bug while making the layout for my Ruby on Rails app.

This is my current layout:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>test</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="mdl-layout mdl-js-layout mdl-layout--fixed-drawer">
      <header class="mdl-layout__header">
        <div class="mdl-layout__header-row">
          <span class="mdl-layout-title">CTC151</span>
        </div>
      </header>
      <div class="mdl-layout__drawer">
        <span class="mdl-layout-title">Test</span>
        <nav class="mdl-navigation">
          <%= link_to('Home', root_path, class: 'mdl-navigation__link') %>
          <%= link_to('News', news_index_path, class: 'mdl-navigation__link') %>
          <%= link_to('Departments', root_path, class: 'mdl-navigation__link') %>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Clicking any link in the navigation drawer will break my layout like so: [before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xsZky.png), [after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nL8e8.png). The whole website becomes confined into that small space at the top. I have removed any personalized stylesheet to make sure it's not the source of the problem. The only stylesheet are the MDL ones and MDL icons

Comment: Can you provide us with a demo that reproduces the problem? I put this together and am not seeing it https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/KvmbWX?editors=1010

Comment: I think this bug has something to do with how MDL was integrated into my project which is through [this](https://github.com/cllns/material_design_lite-rails) gem. Simply including the link into my layout like you did seems to fix my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my website by disabling Turbolinks from my app. There is most likely a workaround but AFAIK MDL doesn't support Turbolinks by default.